# How to simulate CPU bound job

Tags: java, simulation, simulator

I want to simulate CPU bound jobs in my simulator and i need a calculation or code that run for 1 second in the cpu ...how i will do it...
i am using the folllowing code

```
long Time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
///calculation or loop that spends 1 second in cpu
long Time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(Time2-Time1);
```

Now i need the calculation that take 1 second...I also need to simulate for 2 ,3 to 4 seconds
what code i should put in line 2.?

Comment: Is yielding CPU attention for 2, 3, 4 seconds using a "sleep" not acceptable?

Comment: Just put `Time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();` inside a loop that does _anything_ and wait for it to exceed `Time1` by at least a 1000.

Answer (score 0):

If you really meant binding a job to the CPU for 1 second, I don't think it is possible only with pure Java. The reason is that the OS will still remove the process from the CPU, schedule it again and so on for a number of times within 1 second. So you need to make a special kind of request to the OS to do this. The request should go and affect the process scheduling algorithm of the OS. But this is not how we want our applications to consume the CPU. We want the CPU to honor the interrupts and so on. So may be your intension is not clearly mentioned in the question or you might be trying to test something special and uncommon.

If you are just simulating something, may be you might just use a sleep() call as suggested in the comments which actually would not be consuming the CPU for 1 second but allows you to assume so for the simulation purpose.